# How to disable lockdown features for administrators/specific users?

Tags: windows-embedded-7, windows-embedded-8

Using [ELM](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/industry-lockdown-branding-poster.pdf) you can disable modifier keys (such as Win, Alt, etc), but this seems to affect all users, including me.

Is there a way to allow logged-in admins to bypass lockdown features?

[image]

Comment: By reading the documentation it says you can modify these settings with a Powershell script.  So the simplest solution is to run the script as an `Administrator` user.

Comment: @Ramhound I believe ELM is a GUI for those PS scripts.

Comment: Even if thats the case.  They would need to be enabled then disabled as an Administrator.  I can't say one way or another without more knowledge on the PS scripts in question.

Comment: I know an admin has to enable/disable them (I don't understand what point you're making?). I'm trying to enable them for standard users, and disable them for admins.

Comment: **Your question ask how can you allow admins to bypass it**  The answer to that question is write a PS to change allow the keys.  You could make it a login and logout event even

Comment: Ah, I see where you're headed with that now @Ramhound! There is actually an option to *Export to Powershell* in the Action menu. Perhaps you'd like to write an answer? :)

Comment: I don't have the tool.  A proper answer should have the script to enable and disable it.

Comment: I'll post it tomorrow tonight, thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Ramhound

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Keyboard Filter for Administrators.

For Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry, from a PowerShell window or script run:

```
Set-DisableKeyboardFilterForAdministrators $true
```

For Windows Embedded Standard 8, it is a little more complicated because it needs to be disabled via WMI.  Microsoft does have a full script available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj979626(v=winembedded.81).aspx), but in essence you run:

```
    $Setting =$Entry = Get-WMIObject -class WEKF_Settings @{"namespace"="root\standardcimv2\embedded"} |
        where {
            $_.Name -eq "DisableKeyboardFilterForAdministrators"
        }
$setting.Value = "true"
$setting.Put() | Out-Null
```

You can also change the setting in your answer file as well.